# Load RDL report  into Web Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, reporting-services

I am trying to load an (.rdl) report file into a web report viewer control (visual studio 2010 control):

```
    //Get the data and 
    .
    .
    //Add it to report
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(element.Name, dt));

    //Pass the report to the viewer
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(ReportDocument.FileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
       this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
    }
```

Am I missing a line of code somewhere? I used the equivalent for the winforms report viewer with the addition of RefreshReport() - however there is no equivalent method that I could find for web report viewers). The page remains blank - what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

There is a `.Refresh()` method, and that is what you are missing. Here's what I'm using (in VB):

```
ReportViewer1.Reset()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Dispose()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("/reports/" & ReportFile)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource(<datasource>))
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Comment: Ok I added the line you mentioned but this doesn't seem to be the issue - the page is still blank....

Comment: You said in your question that you are trying to load an RDL file. Is it RDL or is it RDLC? RDLC is the format you need for this, with the C standing for Client. RDL files are for use with Reporting Services.

Comment: Why do I need .rdlc? I have a .rdl's - not entirely sure what the difference is? I got this working with the winform.reportviewer

Comment: Actually thinking about it some more RDL reports should be fine. RDL files are compatible with the ReportViewer control. But RDL files don't contain all of the bits the design time of the ReportViewer control depends on for generating databinding. But manually databinding you can be use RDL files with the ReportViewer.

Comment: I perform the manual data binding just fine. RDL's work fine the way I want to use them. A strange observation is that using this.controls.add(reportviewer) causes it to appear...but it has already been dragged across in the designer...